# Task not considered as delivered outside of the sprint

Tags: jira, jira-agile, sprint

I have a task in JIRA that was added to a sprint already in the **Done** status (the farthest right column), and it didn't transition to any other statuses during the sprint. According to my understanding, this task should be considered as **completed outside of the sprint**. However, in the JIRA sprint report for sprint 5, it is categorized as **unplanned**.

Sprint start date: 04/09/2023 12:19:28
Sprint end date: 14/09/2023 12:02:59
[image]

Interestingly, when I replicate this scenario in my private JIRA instance, the task correctly appears in the *completed outside of the sprint* section of the sprint report, as expected.

Why is the task considered *unplanned* instead of *completed outside of the sprint*?